# Conditions on $f$ for applying Cauchy's theorem for integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

> Suppose I want to calculate this integral
>
> $$\int_{|z|=r}\frac{f(z)}{z-1}dz$$
>
> for $0<r<1$ and $r>1$, with $f(z)$ an holomorphic function in all $\Bbb{C}$

For the first case ($0<r<1$), I usually use the common argument that $\frac{f(z)}{z-1}$ is holomorphic in $B(0,r)$ for any $r<1$ and that it is continuous in $\partial B(0,r)$. My problem is the following, it is true that $f$ is continuous in $\partial B(0,r)$ for $every$ $r<1$?

Comment: $\dfrac{f(z)}{z-1}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{1\}$.

Comment: Indeed. But for every $r<1$, you can say that $1 \notin \partial B(0,r)$? That's what Im not sure about.

Comment: Ah. Yes, $\partial B(0,r) = \{ z : \lvert z\rvert = r\}$.